# Is it possible to pass multi line parameter in jenkins as text file in scripted pipeline?

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

Instead of having the text set within the parameter in the jenkinsfile, is it possible to read text for multiline parameter from a file for scripted pipeline.

example of the parameter in jenkins file

```
text(defaultValue: "years of mismanagement and poor conditions in stores have hurt Family Dollar’s brand. The company has struggled as discount competitors such as Dollar General, Walmart and others grew. More recently, inflation has hit Family Dollar customers and the chain’s profits.Persistent inflation and reduced government benefits continue to pressure the lower-income consumers that comprise a sizable portion of Family Dollar’s” customer base" description: '', name: 'SAMPLE_TEXT')
```

Tried file parameter but It does not work within scripted pipeline.

Comment: Are you asking about assigning the `defaultValue` from file content?

Comment: Yes, is it possible to read content of default value for multiline parameter?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `readFile` basic pipeline step to achieve this:

```
text(defaultValue: readFile(file: 'my_file.txt'), description: '', name: 'SAMPLE_TEXT')
```

More information can be found in the [documentation](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#readfile-read-file-from-workspace).

Comment: readFile is only used if the file is in the workspace. Are there any options if the file is not part of the workspace but on the vm you're ssh to?

Comment: That would be external data, and that would not really be part of the pipeline parameters. Also the build agent user typically does not have permissions to read files outside of the workpace.